# Unable to upload images to the Media Library. Getting this erron on the console wp-admin/async-upload.php 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I haven't been able to upload images on the Media Library, neither on pages or post, succesfully.

I've got this errors:

*An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.* **(On WordPress dashboard)**

*wp-admin/async-upload.php 403 (Forbidden)* **(On the browser console)**

I already fix the uploads folders permissions to 755, disable plugins and changed to the default WordPress themes but nothing solves the problem.

Also, there are happening three weird things:

1. The files that I tried to upload, are saved on the uploads folder when I check them on FileZilla. (But it keeps showing the errors listed above).
2. No images are displayed on the grid layout on the Media Library, while there displayed on the list layout.
3. When I try to upload an image, the progress bar gets to 100% and then gets stuck on *Crunching*

I'm currently using WordPress 4.7.4

Any thoughts out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I think I know the answer, however, I haven't found a way to solve the problem. When I checked all the php files in my File Manager I noticed that none of the php files ended correctly. A php code is supposed to start like this: 
Each one of the files I checked until now did not have "?>" this part. But I haven't found a way to insert it into every php file in one time. I hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: It is not required that a php file ends with the closing '?>'. In fact, maybe not good, as any extraneous space characters after the closing tag will show up in the generated page, which might cause other errors.